# Visual Studio 2012 auto-generated code conflicting with application code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Im really new to working with VS2012, but I am getting a really big problem thats making development impossible. Every time I change some code, I get conflicts with code auto-generated by VS2012 for debugging ( project\obj\Release\filename.g.i.css ). It's like there are ghost copies of source files and VS2012 is picking them up as project files and causing lots of declaration errors (because it detects them as declared in two places, even though its technically the same file).

So if I change Main.xaml.cs and save, VS2012 generates Main.g.i.css, tells me the source file has been changed outside of VS2012 and Main.g.i.css is full of a bunch of code I didn't put there, and this is at the top of its source:

This code was generated by a tool.
Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.

I have turned off the file auto-reloading in options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add the `*.g.*` files to the Visual Studio project. They are included automatically by the build process and is probably why you are seeing duplicates and conflicts.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the quick reply. How can I go about getting the build process to not add those files?

Comment: They should not be added by default. Check whether the `obj` folder and its contents are included in the project. If so, remove them.

Comment: Nope, they are definitely not included in the project, atleast they are not showing up in the solution explorer.

Comment: Maybe create a new project and readd all the files or something. Somehow, the *.g.* files are being included when they should not be.

Comment: Ive been through a couple projects already and eventually the problem occurs no matter what.

Comment: Are you running any add-ins to Visual Studio? IF so, try disabling them and see if the problem recurs.

Comment: I don't think I'm running any plugins for VS2012, but I think I can try and describe my problem better after dealing with it for a bit longer. Here is a screenshot of how I keep ending up into the .g files, http://gyazo.com/ca607e1aa61a7f2fea15b335ebed7ac3 , as you can see, whenever I try to browse the source code of App.xaml.cs , it comes up as it should, with only code generated by creating a new Visual C# WPF project ( reference http://pastebin.com/xK0WWc28 ), but the file in that screenshot (the g.i version of App.xaml.cs) contains the entrypoint and initializecomponent code I need to edit

Comment: Hit the char limit, sorry. So now, whenever I try to edit that code it edits the g.i. version, and that ends up making all my changes to it moot because it autoreloads that file because Im not even supposed to be editing it afaik. Any idea whats going on? I think I may just be really confused, this is something I hadn't experienced in VS2010's solution explorer.

Comment: Never edit the *.g.* files directly. In WPF, these are usually generated from the XAML files and are usually `partial` classes. For example, if you need to edit `InitializeCompnent()`, add code before or after the call to it in the constructor in the `.xaml.cs` file instead.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because ultimately it was correct. I was editing the .g. files, because they contained the Main() for the application, I didn't know that I could just overwrite this in my own class without editing those files. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this problem as well. I think a combination of hitting Build -> Clean and deleting the obj/ folders eventually solved my problem.

Comment: I gave this a try but with no luck. VS2012 still thinks the .g. files are part of my project and cites errors/conflicts with those files.